# How can I compute virtual array via convolution?

Tags: convolution, mimo

I am starting to learn MIMO transceivers and I would like to compute the virtual array of my configuration. To do so, I am following these set of equations 2 and 3, to achieve (3) I was trying to use Matlab `conv` and `conv2` but the results that I am getting are not the one I would expect as if I do the direct implementation of the summation.

[image]

Let's say that my Location functions are the followings, referred as $\lambda$ distances

```matlab
L_Tx = [ -0.1292   -0.1216   -0.1140
          0         0         0        ]
L_Rx = [ -0.1130   -0.1111   -0.1092   -0.1074
         0         0         0         0]
```

Computing the convolution of both above leads to

```matlab
virtualPos  = conv2(L_Tx,L_Rx)

virtualPos =

    0.0146    0.0281    0.0405    0.0398    0.0255    0.0122
         0         0         0         0         0         0
         0         0         0         0         0         0
```

However, if I implement direct summation with

```
virtualPos = [];
for i = 1:size(T1,2)
    for j = 1:size(R1,2)
        virtualPos = [virtualPos (T1(:,i)+R1(:,j))] 
    end
end

virtualPos =

   -0.2423   -0.2404   -0.2384   -0.2366   -0.2346   -0.2328   -0.2308   -0.2289   -0.2271   -0.2252   -0.2233   -0.2213
         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
```

I do know that the output of direct summation is correct because it is my expected result, so I am definitely understanding something wrong or using the convolution wrongly, any hints on what I am overlooking?

Thank you in advance!